# Parse hierarchy column in SQL

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have the following data in BigQuery:

```
| id | category    |
|----|-------------| 
| 1  | Age groups  |
| 2  |   0-17      |
| 3  |     0-5     |
| 4  |     6-17    |
| 5  |       6-10  |
| 6  |       11-17 |
| 7  |   18-30     |
| 8  |     18-24   |
| 9  |     25-30   |
| 10 |   31-50     |
| 11 |   51 and up |
```

Each category has a subcategory that is defined using indentations. The number of levels is dynamic and I'd like to flatten the category column and have the following output:

```
| id | category_flatten                 |
|----|----------------------------------| 
| 1  | Age groups                       |
| 2  | Age groups > 0-17                |
| 3  | Age groups > 0-17 > 0-5          |
| 4  | Age groups > 0-17 > 6-17         |
| 5  | Age groups > 0-17 > 6-17 > 6-10  |
| 6  | Age groups > 0-17 > 6-17 > 11-17 |
| 7  | Age groups > 18-30               |
| 8  | Age groups > 18-30 > 18-24       |
| 9  | Age groups > 18-30 > 25-30       |
| 10 | Age groups > 31-50               |
| 11 | Age groups > 51 and up           |
```

I know this can be done in Python (as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45964731/how-to-parse-hierarchy-based-on-indents-with-python)) but I'm wondering if this could be done in SQL.

Comment: `0-17` and `0-5` seem to be on the same level, don't they?

Comment: Oops I kinda missed that. Thanks for pointing it out, edited the table.

Comment: SQL is not the right tool to do this. It can be done, but it's cumbersome and error prone.